Postgres SQL get unique combination of data from 2 columns
For an hour tried to solve it with Claude, 4o, Perplexity, but could not.
Then found similar example SQL distinct on 2 columns , with 3 options how to solve - first option gave error "rn" column not found, second option ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950364/7284577 ) gave me 6 of 7 rows, and last one I could not run.
That is why will ask here.
Have table time_user
id;user_id_1;user_id_2
51353;21014;21013
51352;21012;21013
51351;21011;21013
51350;21010;21011
51349;21015;21010
51348;21014;21010
51347;21013;21010

INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51353, 21014, 21013);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51352, 21012, 21013);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51351, 21011, 21013);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51350, 21010, 21011);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51349, 21015, 21010);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51348, 21014, 21010);
INSERT INTO "time_user" ("id", "user_id_1", "user_id_2") VALUES (51347, 21013, 21010);

If we will sort by desc 'id' column and will start to collect rows with distinct user_id_ in both columns (user_id_1, user_id_2), then we should take 51353 (with 21014 and 21013), then we ignore 51352 and 51351, becuse they have user_id_2==21013 which is already was in ID 51353, then we take id 51350 cuz it have user_ids 21010 and 21011. 51349-51347 should be ignored, because user_ids from these rows where in 51353 and 51350.
The closest solve was given bt Perplexity, and it returned 51353 only:
WITH UniqueUsers AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        user_id_1,
        user_id_2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
    FROM time_user
),
Filtered AS (
    SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.user_id_1,
        u.user_id_2,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM UniqueUsers f 
         WHERE f.rn < u.rn 
         AND (f.user_id_1 IN (u.user_id_1, u.user_id_2) 
              OR f.user_id_2 IN (u.user_id_1, u.user_id_2))) AS duplicate_count
    FROM UniqueUsers u
)
SELECT id
FROM Filtered
WHERE duplicate_count = 0 ORDER BY id DESC;

I want to receive 51353 and 51350
Or in other words: want to retrieve the id's in which they have an unique combination of user_id1 and user_id_2

I see sample data, but no actual problem statement.

@TimBiegeleisen I can not write query which will return 51353 and 51350 ids from my table.

"I want to receive 51353 and 51350" can be achieved by doing SELECT 51353, 51350; or select 51353 union  select 51350;.  Please read How to ask "The title is the first thing that potential answerers will see. If your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. Also, without a good title, people may not even be able to find your question."

@Luuk I need to find these values ​​via user_id_ columns not via id.

@Vit if i understand well your problem here. You want to retrieve the id which they have an unique combination of user_id1 and user_id_2 ?

@francoisLENNE Yes, it is!

okay little advice update your post with this explanation !

@Vit i'm working on your problem from my perspective all the id have an unique combination of user_id_1 and user_id_2 base on the insert into you give it

SELECT id, user_id_1,user_id_2 FROM (
     SELECT id, user_id_1,user_id_2, row_number() over (order by id desc) as R
     FROM "time_user" 
) t3
WHERE R=1 
  or ( user_id_1 not in (select user_id_1 from "time_user" t2 where t2.id <> t3.id)
       and user_id_2 not in (select user_id_2 from "time_user" t2 where t2.id <> t3.id))

This will:

Select the first row (R=1)
Select all rows where user_id_1 is not in another row and user_id_2 is not in another row

see: DBFIDDLE
output:



id
user_id_1
user_id_2




51353
21014
21013


51350
21010
21011



